# How to format pandas datetime?

Tags: pandas, datetime-format, strptime, strftime

I have a pandas series with normal dates, say 2017-01-01. I'm trying to call it in a lambda function, but if I cal row['date'], it returns '2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'. What is the right format to convert it to a datetime using strptime?

Appreciate the help

Comment: is your Series in type of datetime? Maybe `pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y%m%d')` ??

Comment: don't think it's really necessary- the only relevant datapoint is the date string  '2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000000' how do I convert that to datetime using strptime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000000','2017-01-02T00:00:00.000000000','2017-01-03T00:00:00.000000000']})`

You can convert the whole column with `pd.to_datetime`.

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
0   2017-01-01
1   2017-01-02
2   2017-01-03
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

>>> df['date'][0]
Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')
```

If you have an individual cell, you can also use `pd.to_datetime`

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000000')
Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')
```

And then `strftime` if needed:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000000').strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
'2017/01/01'
```

But converting individual cell is faster with `pd.Timestamp`:

```
>>> %timeit pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000000')
2.18 µs ± 8.56 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %timeit pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000000')
54 µs ± 560 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Is there no way to use strptime? I'm calling the date in a lambda function and it returns it to me in a weird format. When I try to do apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['date']) it gives me the error ValueError: ('Unknown string format', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Can you print its value in a function?